# Create an overflow navbar menu in AngularJS

Tags: drop-down-menu, angularjs, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to achieve a horizontal navbar overflow menu in AngularJS, like on http://www.outlook.com  or this jquery example http://jebaird.com/blog/overflow-menu-jquery-ui-widget.

i.e. when the screen is resized horizontally, the menu items that will not fit on the screen are pushed into the last menu item (e.g. one named "..."). When there is little horizontal space all of the menu items are still available to the user.

How do I get the items that have overflowed and how can I move them to the last menu item?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?  I believe you might be able to accomplish this with just CSS.

Comment: Only the latest Chrome and IE for the moment

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this with just CSS, you'll need Javascript.  I'd be very surprised if there aren't libraries out there that do this for you.